# What's a word for being very blunt and literal?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find the word for being very blunt and literal for example, when you ask someone what they're up to when they are going somewhere and they reply with "walking" or when someone is mixing powder in water and you ask what they're doing and they say "stirring" or you ask what they've got for dinner and they say "food"

I think you get the idea, I've been trying to find the word for this for ages, appreciate the help.

Comment: What's wrong with "blunt"? These all seem to be "blunt" replies.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit the question; word or phrase requests must include an example sentence showing how the word would be used.

Comment: Lots of single words could describe this situation but not be exactly specific to it. There's nothing wrong with more than one word. Did you check a thesaurus for blunt or literal?

Comment: For some unannounced reason, my claiming [Is there an expression for someone who often takes things too literally?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173651/is-there-an-expression-for-someone-who-often-takes-things-too-literally/173652#173652) as a duplicate has not registered in the way expected. Literalist / literal are answers there. The question contains a SWR tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an expression for someone who often takes things too literally?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173651/is-there-an-expression-for-someone-who-often-takes-things-too-literally)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure you used the duplicate close reason? When I voted to close this, there were 2 existing close votes, but neither was for the duplicate reason.

Comment: I'm not seeing answers that capture the deliberately unhelpful flavor of the replies. Unfortunately, I can't think of a single word that fits. There's the related idea of the "mathematician's answer" which is technically true, but useless.

Comment: @cigien Almost sure. One has to click on the suggested duplicate thread, which I did. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, thanks. I was just checking, because if you *had* chosen to close as a duplicate, it would be a bug. If you're unsure though, it's more likely that it's just a misclick (or some user error).

Comment: **Terse** -> sparing in the use of words; abrupt. (Oxford Dictionaries).

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts you could try **point-blank**; if you wished to be less disapproving of perceived impoliteness, try **forthright**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/point-blank)
>
> point-blank:
> saying something very clearly in very few words, without trying to be polite or pleasant:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/point-blank)
>
> forthright:
> (too) honest or direct in behaviour:
> *His forthright manner can be mistaken for rudeness.*

Answer (score 1):

If the emphasis is how brief the replies are, **terse** is a good fit:

- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terse): 1: using few words : devoid of superfluity
  *a terse summary*
  also : SHORT, BRUSQUE
  *dismissed me with a terse "no"*